# converting UNIX time stamp date to the Monday of that week

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp

how can i convert a time stamp to Monday corresponding with that week?

example:
1473750000   (Tue, 13 Sep 2016 07:00:00 GMT)

// coding magic

1473638400   (Mon, 12 Sep 2016 00:00:00 GMT )

Comment: http://php.net/date  specifically the "day of week" formatting option, then some simple math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert timestamps, you can use a PHP Function `gmdate()`. I already use this on some of my projects/sites.

```
$timestamp = strtotime("+1 hour"); //Uk Time
echo gmdate("H:i", $timestamp); //Hour:Minutes
```

For the other parts of `gmdate()`, check the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php).

Answer (score 1):

I also add my solution to the problem, using DateInterval.

```
function getLastMonday($timestamp){
    // Initialize DateTime object
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimestamp($timestamp);

    // Calculate num of days to substract and create date interval
    $dayOfWeek = $date->format("w");
    $interval = new DateInterval("P".(($dayOfWeek+6)%7).'D');
    $interval->invert = 1;

    // Substract the Date interval
    $date->add($interval);

    return $date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer using the documentation provided in the answers:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('this monday this week',1473750000));
```